# Azure App Reply URL Caching?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

We're setting up SAML2 SSO using Azure AD, and we set the Reply URL incorrectly the first time. Now, I am unable to login with the original credentials we tested with as they are being redirected to the incorrect Reply URL. Any new user accounts work fine.

I'm unable to find any documentation saying how long this type of caching may take place, but I've cleared all client-side caches and am at a loss for what we could do without recreating the app (which we'd like to try to avoid).

Comment: Um.. I came to this issue sometimes. You can try to delete the old one and add a new application to configure it.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Thanks for the thoughts, given the amount of configuration tied to the app we were trying to avoid recreating it. Will keep that in mind for next time though.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Did you end up having to recreate it?

Comment: @marileeturscak-MSFT I was not able to resolve the issue per say. We worked around it by creating new user accounts, instead of recreating the ap, due mostly to time constraints.